# openjdk8-based container never crashes with JVM's own OOM exceptions; always killed by docker with error 137

Tags: docker, jvm

So we have a medium-sized JVM-based application and since a week or two it's being OOM-killed regularly by docker. I have read everything I could find on Java 8 memory consumption in containers, the experimental `cgroup` flag, MaxRAM, controlling non-heap size, optimizing the GC and so on. But there is no way to get the JVM to throw its own OOM exception in our case. It's always docker that's killing it with code 137.

---

E.g. when giving `2000M` of memory to the container and setting the heap to `80%` of that:

`-XX:MaxRAM=1600M -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2`

which means the heap will grow up to 800M, the result is still an OOM-kill by docker. We started out with `-Xmx` between `800M` and `1600M` - same result.

---

When controlling the non-heap size (assuming a max of 100 threads):

`-XX:MaxRAM=1050M -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1 -Xss1M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=64M -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=128M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128M`

and arriving at `(100 * Xss) + 128M + 64M + 128M + 128M = 548M` for the entire non-heap part of JVM memory requirements, we take the `2000M` of container memory minus a margin of `20%` minus the `548M` non-heap giving us `-XX:MaxRAM=1050M` and still we get OOM-killed.

Not sure if it matters but we run a DC/OS cluster and it's Marathon reporting the task kills due to OOM. But my understanding is that it's the underlying docker engine's behaviour that gets reported.

Comment: The formula is not accurate. JVM may take much more RAM, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438) for details.

Comment: @apangin thanks. Seems the issue is complicated. Are some parts of the formula of your answer's conclusion neither part of the heap nor the non-heap? Yourkit is reporting a very slowly growing heap and non-heap while the container's memory footprint is growing much faster, making me think some other part of the JVM might be responsible

Comment: 'Non-heap' in YourKit includes only Code Cache, Metaspace and Compressed Class Space. Everything else is not counted.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the version of the Open JDK 8 you are using. Oracle backported the support for cgroups limits to Open JDK 8u131. Please see [this Oracle blog article](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-se-support-for-docker-cpu-and-memory-limits) and a [shorter explanation](https://blog.csanchez.org/2017/05/31/running-a-jvm-in-a-container-without-getting-killed/). The latter one has some useful snippets to check if JVM correctly sets heap size inside the container.

If in your case, the JVM sets heap size correctly, I would check for a memory leak in the app.