# Does the jvm code cache area exist in heap or metaspace?

Tags: jvm

There's nothing I can found this question .

Does the JVM code cache area exist in heap or metaspace in jdk 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither in Heap nor in Metaspace. In HotSpot JVM Code Cache is a separate off-heap area. Its size is controlled by `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize` option.

On the "Memory" tab of Java Mission Control you'll find the Code Cache among other JVM memory pools:

[image: JVM memory pools]

[More about JVM memory areas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624438/3448419)