# JVM being OOMKilled by k8s limited pod even with Xmx and MaxDirectMemorySize

Tags: kubernetes, memory-management, jvm, out-of-memory, jvm-arguments

For some time we've had a problem in our production environment about one of our JVM pods having *seemingly* random spikes of memory usage. This sometimes leads to the JVM process being OOMKilled by the Kernel, as it would otherwise go over the memory limit set through kubernetes. This also leads to no OOM Error being thrown, and therefor, no JVM Heapdump being made.

Initially, all we had was `-Xmx900m` to limit the maximum heap. The pod itself was limited to `2000Mi`, which is corresponds to `2097.15MB`. So, in theory this shouldn't be a problem, right? Well it still was, as different parts like `direct memory` etc. are not limited by that, and lead to over usage of memory.

So, I've been doing some reading and added some flags, enabled some other things, with the hopes of making the JVM *kill itself* before the kernel, so it could do a *heapdump* for us to analyse.

At the same time we added a new node to be able to just increase the pod limits (hey, maybe it's just more users? Would be okay...)

So after some changes, this is our new setup. The pod is now limited to `2500Mi` or `2621.44MB`, and the JVM has the following flags applied:

```
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=900m 
-Xmx1200m 
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/pod-dump.bin 
-Xlog:gc*:file=/tmp/gc.log:time,level,tags:filecount=4,filesize=50M
```

Long story short: It's still dying through Kernel induced OOMKilled. Therefor, no Heapdump is being created.

Using `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail`, I can get further details on the JVM, and the first thing I realised is the first line:

`Total: reserved=2448034KB, committed=750586KB`

From what I understand is that `reserved` resembles the total memory space the JVM thinks it can *use*, but isn't actually *committed* to any real memory addresses(This article goes above and beyond to explain this stuff https://blog.arkey.fr/2020/11/30/off-heap-reconnaissance/). If we convert it, we get `2390.65MB`, which is above our pod limits! So, in theory this seems to be the reason why the kernel still has to OOMKill the process.

The next step was to check the JVM flags. We do set some, but others are set automatically, so maybe we can find something there? (For clarity sake I only show the flags which seem interesting:

```
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=1048576 
-XX:MarkStackSize=4194304 
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=943718400 
-XX:MaxHeapSize=1258291200 
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=536870912 
-XX:MaxNewSize=754974720 
-XX:SoftMaxHeapSize=1258291200
```

So as we set `Xmx1200m`, `MaxHeapSize` and `SoftMaxHeapSize` are the same, namely `1200 MB`. The next one is `MaxDirectMemorySize`, which is also correct and evaluates to `700MB`. Now the question is, which of these *other* flags contribute to the *total JVM memory usage*, or the Total reserved` amount?

My intuition tells me that to *calculate* the possible *maximum amount of memory* the JVM could use before going *OOM* (itself, not kernel, also ignoring that Heap can go OOM without the complete JVM going OOM) I can do the sum of some of these flags:
`MarkStackSize + MaxDirectMemorySize + MaxHeapSize + MaxMetaspaceSize + MaxNewSize`, which results in a total of `3336MB`, which is way above the pod limits!
What might also be interesting is that `MaxRAM` *changed* after the pod limits were adapted, and is now `MaxRAM=2621440000` or `2500MB`, which perfectly reflects the pod limits. So here is another question: If the *JVM* can correctly figure out the possible `MaxRAM`, why does it not set flags that aren't manually set to accommodate for that?

Quite possibly I'm absolutely in the wrong here and misunderstood quite a bit about JVM + Memory usage, but from what I understood we either lack some flags, or are forced to *manually set everything* to make sure it does not go over it.

*Additional information*:
We are using temurin_17 image, and use Spring + GRPC-java for our application (which uses netty, which is where most native memory usage is coming from), and we are using `G1GC` as garbage collector

Comment: This likely won't solve your problem and it's often better to be explicit, but you can also use `MaxRAMPercentage` for more dynamic setting instead of the fixed size: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64408245/kubernetes-and-jvm-memory-settings/64410587#64410587

Comment: @JurajMartinka Thanks for the comment. Sadly, `MaxRAMPercentage` only limits the heap size, and does not set a global memory usage limit for the complete JVM process.

Comment: Sure, as you'll learn (or learned) in the question linked at the top, there's no such magic switch for limiting the total JVM memory consumption. If you limit heap enough, then you might get what you need (the OOM dump) before it's killed due to hitting the total memory limit. Btw. if this is somewhat predictable you can proactively make an OOM dump (with `jcmd` or something else) before the process is killed.