# Is -XX:-UseContainerSupport with -XX:MaxRAMPercentage automatically calculates other JVM resources size?

Tags: performance, docker, jvm

From Java 8 update 191 or later, or Java 10, 11,12, 13 etc. We have option called `XX:+UseContainerSupport` that is activated by default, so JVM can read limits for RAM And CPU inside container.
With setting `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90.0` I can tell JVM how much % of available RAM I want give to HEAP, **but what about [other JVM resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi)?** like GC, CodeCache, ClassLoading, Metaspace, DirectBuffers and so on?

Does JVM also adapt its sizes (to left space after allocating heap) to not get over available RAM?
Or do I still have to calculate it by myself in each case like following:

```
-XX:MetaspaceSize=64m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=32m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=16m -Xss256k
```

For example if create a container with 1G RAM and run in it JVM with `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90.0`, so HEAP will take 900m, and there is will be only 100m for other JVM stuff, does this 100m will be intellectually distributed between all required resources, like setting `XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` (which is unlimited by default) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to the linked question also refers to my [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c755fFv1Rnk), where I explain that so called "container support" in JDK  affects nothing but

- The default heap size
- The number of available CPUs

So, the answer is NO: JVM does not resize other memory areas and does not attempt to satisfy container limits in any other way. You need to control them manually.

Comment: The vimeo link is unfortunately dead now. Do you have a working one please?

Comment: @DavideMadrisan Thanks for the notice. I've updated the link to the same presentation at another event.

Comment: The talk is excellent :)