# UBUNTU Minecraft Paper Server Insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu-18.04, minecraft, jvm-arguments

I have a Microsoft Azure VM Instance Running on which I have minecraft paper server installed. Today I'm not able to start the server due to some java error caused while running the server command via ssh-putty.

**Server OS:** Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

**Minecraft Server Run Commands:**

```
sudo java -Xms29G -Xmx29G -jar paper-1.16.4-416.jar nogui

                             OR

java -Xmx29G -Xms29G -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=45 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=50 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=80 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=10 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=50 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -jar paper-1.16.4-416.jar
```

**Server Statistics:**
[image: Server Statistics]

**Server Specifications:**

```
H/W path      Device      Class      Description
================================================
                          system     Virtual Machine
/0                        bus        Virtual Machine
/0/0                      memory     64KiB BIOS
/0/5                      processor  AMD EPYC 7452 32-Core Processor
/0/51                     memory     32GiB System Memory
/0/51/0                   memory     1GiB
/0/51/1                   memory     31GiB
/0/100                    bridge     440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (AGP disabled)
/0/100/7                  bridge     82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA
/0/100/7.1                storage    82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE
/0/100/7.3                bridge     82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI
/0/100/8                  display    Hyper-V virtual VGA
/0/2          enP1s1      network    MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx Virtual Function]
/0/1          scsi0       storage
/0/1/0.0.0    /dev/sda    disk       32GB Virtual Disk
/0/1/0.0.0/1  /dev/sda1   volume     29GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/e  /dev/sda14  volume     4095KiB BIOS Boot partition
/0/1/0.0.0/f  /dev/sda15  volume     105MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/3          scsi3       storage
/0/3/0.0.0    /dev/sdb    disk       34GB Virtual Disk
/0/4          scsi1       storage
/0/4/0.1.0    /dev/sdc    disk       68GB Virtual Disk
/0/4/0.1.0/1  /dev/sdc1   volume     63GiB EXT4 volume
/1            eth0        network    Ethernet interface
```

**/proc/meminfo :**

```
MemTotal:       32888792 kB
MemFree:        32571152 kB
MemAvailable:   32352944 kB
Buffers:            4644 kB
Cached:            78888 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           126612 kB
Inactive:          26428 kB
Active(anon):      69508 kB
Inactive(anon):      712 kB
Active(file):      57104 kB
Inactive(file):    25716 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               272 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         69544 kB
Mapped:            40804 kB
Shmem:               720 kB
KReclaimable:      28200 kB
Slab:              86412 kB
SReclaimable:      28200 kB
SUnreclaim:        58212 kB
KernelStack:        2640 kB
PageTables:         4460 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    16444396 kB
Committed_AS:     274404 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       27516 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             2400 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:      2048 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      131008 kB
DirectMap2M:     4063232 kB
DirectMap1G:    31457280 kB
```

**Error:**

```
root@MinecraftServer:/srv/minecraft-server# sudo java -Xms29G -Xmx29G -jar paper-1.16.4-416.jar nogui
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000c0000000, 31138512896, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 31138512896 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /srv/minecraft-server/hs_err_pid4437.log
```

**/srv/minecraft-server/hs_err_pid4437.log :**

```
---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x0000557180b3e2b0, length=0, elements={
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:
  0x00007f8e3402e800 GCTaskThread "GC Thread#0" [stack: 0x00007f8e3811e000,0x00007f8e3821e000] [id=4439]
  0x00007f8e3406b800 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Main Marker" [stack: 0x00007f8e1c3ad000,0x00007f8e1c4ad000] [id=4440]
  0x00007f8e3406d000 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Conc#0" [stack: 0x00007f8e1c2ab000,0x00007f8e1c3ab000] [id=4441]

[error occurred during error reporting (printing all threads), id 0xb, SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8e3a73da20]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00007f8e34013210] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f8e34016800

Heap address: 0x00000000c0000000, size: 29696 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Non-zero based: 0x00000000c0000000
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 0

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (2 events):
Event: 0.001 Protecting memory [0x00007f8e3c267000,0x00007f8e3c26b000] with protection modes 0
Event: 0.001 Loaded shared library /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libzip.so


Dynamic libraries:
557180084000-557180085000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 258537                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
557180285000-557180286000 r--p 00001000 08:01 258537                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
557180286000-557180287000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 258537                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
557180b26000-557180b47000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f8dc4000000-7f8dc4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8dc4021000-7f8dc8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8dcc000000-7f8dcc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8dcc021000-7f8dd0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8dd0ffe000-7f8dd3200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8dd3200000-7f8e18000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e18000000-7f8e18021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e18021000-7f8e1c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e1c0a7000-7f8e1c2a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e1c2a9000-7f8e1c2aa000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e1c2aa000-7f8e1c3ab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e1c3ab000-7f8e1c3ac000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e1c3ac000-7f8e1c899000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e1c899000-7f8e1cb09000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e1cb09000-7f8e1ce29000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e1ce29000-7f8e1d099000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e1d099000-7f8e24361000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e24361000-7f8e245d1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e245d1000-7f8e2b899000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e2b899000-7f8e34000000 r--s 00000000 08:01 258700                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/modules
7f8e34000000-7f8e34088000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e34088000-7f8e38000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3801b000-7f8e3811c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3811c000-7f8e3811d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3811d000-7f8e38223000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e38223000-7f8e38309000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e38309000-7f8e3830e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3830e000-7f8e383f4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e383f4000-7f8e383fb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 258699                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libzip.so
7f8e383fb000-7f8e385fa000 ---p 00007000 08:01 258699                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libzip.so
7f8e385fa000-7f8e385fb000 r--p 00006000 08:01 258699                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libzip.so
7f8e385fb000-7f8e385fc000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 258699                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libzip.so
7f8e385fc000-7f8e38607000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2235                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.27.so
7f8e38607000-7f8e38806000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 2235                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.27.so
7f8e38806000-7f8e38807000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 2235                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.27.so
7f8e38807000-7f8e38808000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 2235                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.27.so
7f8e38808000-7f8e3880e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3880e000-7f8e38825000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2232                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.27.so
7f8e38825000-7f8e38a24000 ---p 00017000 08:01 2232                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.27.so
7f8e38a24000-7f8e38a25000 r--p 00016000 08:01 2232                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.27.so
7f8e38a25000-7f8e38a26000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 2232                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.27.so
7f8e38a26000-7f8e38a28000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e38a28000-7f8e38a33000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2237                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.27.so
7f8e38a33000-7f8e38c32000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 2237                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.27.so
7f8e38c32000-7f8e38c33000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 2237                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.27.so
7f8e38c33000-7f8e38c34000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 2237                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.27.so
7f8e38c34000-7f8e38c3c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2233                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.27.so
7f8e38c3c000-7f8e38e3c000 ---p 00008000 08:01 2233                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.27.so
7f8e38e3c000-7f8e38e3d000 r--p 00008000 08:01 2233                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.27.so
7f8e38e3d000-7f8e38e3e000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 2233                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.27.so
7f8e38e3e000-7f8e38e43000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 258682                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjimage.so
7f8e38e43000-7f8e39042000 ---p 00005000 08:01 258682                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjimage.so
7f8e39042000-7f8e39043000 r--p 00004000 08:01 258682                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjimage.so
7f8e39043000-7f8e39044000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 258682                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjimage.so
7f8e39044000-7f8e3906d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 258678                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjava.so
7f8e3906d000-7f8e3926d000 ---p 00029000 08:01 258678                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjava.so
7f8e3926d000-7f8e3926e000 r--p 00029000 08:01 258678                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjava.so
7f8e3926e000-7f8e3926f000 rw-p 0002a000 08:01 258678                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjava.so
7f8e3926f000-7f8e39270000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e39270000-7f8e3927d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 258698                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libverify.so
7f8e3927d000-7f8e3947c000 ---p 0000d000 08:01 258698                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libverify.so
7f8e3947c000-7f8e3947e000 r--p 0000c000 08:01 258698                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libverify.so
7f8e3947e000-7f8e3947f000 rw-p 0000e000 08:01 258698                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libverify.so
7f8e3947f000-7f8e39486000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2242                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.27.so
7f8e39486000-7f8e39685000 ---p 00007000 08:01 2242                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.27.so
7f8e39685000-7f8e39686000 r--p 00006000 08:01 2242                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.27.so
7f8e39686000-7f8e39687000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 2242                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.27.so
7f8e39687000-7f8e3969e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2220                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8e3969e000-7f8e3989d000 ---p 00017000 08:01 2220                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8e3989d000-7f8e3989e000 r--p 00016000 08:01 2220                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8e3989e000-7f8e3989f000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 2220                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8e3989f000-7f8e39a3c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2229                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
7f8e39a3c000-7f8e39c3b000 ---p 0019d000 08:01 2229                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
7f8e39c3b000-7f8e39c3c000 r--p 0019c000 08:01 2229                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
7f8e39c3c000-7f8e39c3d000 rw-p 0019d000 08:01 2229                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
7f8e39c3d000-7f8e39db6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6263                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
7f8e39db6000-7f8e39fb6000 ---p 00179000 08:01 6263                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
7f8e39fb6000-7f8e39fc0000 r--p 00179000 08:01 6263                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
7f8e39fc0000-7f8e39fc2000 rw-p 00183000 08:01 6263                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
7f8e39fc2000-7f8e39fc6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e39fc6000-7f8e3b1b7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 258705                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so
7f8e3b1b7000-7f8e3b3b6000 ---p 011f1000 08:01 258705                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so
7f8e3b3b6000-7f8e3b477000 r--p 011f0000 08:01 258705                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so
7f8e3b477000-7f8e3b4b2000 rw-p 012b1000 08:01 258705                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so
7f8e3b4b2000-7f8e3b509000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3b509000-7f8e3b523000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2240                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7f8e3b523000-7f8e3b722000 ---p 0001a000 08:01 2240                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7f8e3b722000-7f8e3b723000 r--p 00019000 08:01 2240                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7f8e3b723000-7f8e3b724000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 2240                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7f8e3b724000-7f8e3b728000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3b728000-7f8e3b72b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2228                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f8e3b72b000-7f8e3b92a000 ---p 00003000 08:01 2228                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f8e3b92a000-7f8e3b92b000 r--p 00002000 08:01 2228                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f8e3b92b000-7f8e3b92c000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 2228                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f8e3b92c000-7f8e3b948000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2174                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7f8e3b948000-7f8e3bb47000 ---p 0001c000 08:01 2174                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7f8e3bb47000-7f8e3bb48000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 2174                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7f8e3bb48000-7f8e3bb49000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 2174                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7f8e3bb49000-7f8e3bd30000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2225                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f8e3bd30000-7f8e3bf30000 ---p 001e7000 08:01 2225                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f8e3bf30000-7f8e3bf34000 r--p 001e7000 08:01 2225                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f8e3bf34000-7f8e3bf36000 rw-p 001eb000 08:01 2225                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f8e3bf36000-7f8e3bf3a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3bf3a000-7f8e3bf4a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 258662                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jli/libjli.so
7f8e3bf4a000-7f8e3c149000 ---p 00010000 08:01 258662                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jli/libjli.so
7f8e3c149000-7f8e3c14a000 r--p 0000f000 08:01 258662                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jli/libjli.so
7f8e3c14a000-7f8e3c14b000 rw-p 00010000 08:01 258662                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jli/libjli.so
7f8e3c14b000-7f8e3c174000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2221                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f8e3c1d7000-7f8e3c258000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3c258000-7f8e3c25f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3c25f000-7f8e3c267000 rw-s 00000000 08:01 521011                     /tmp/hsperfdata_root/4437
7f8e3c267000-7f8e3c26b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3c26b000-7f8e3c36a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3c370000-7f8e3c371000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3c371000-7f8e3c372000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3c372000-7f8e3c374000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8e3c374000-7f8e3c375000 r--p 00029000 08:01 2221                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f8e3c375000-7f8e3c376000 rw-p 0002a000 08:01 2221                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f8e3c376000-7f8e3c377000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffc98ba6000-7ffc98bc7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc98bd6000-7ffc98bd9000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc98bd9000-7ffc98bda000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms29G -Xmx29G
java_command: paper-1.16.4-416.jar nogui
java_class_path (initial): paper-1.16.4-416.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

[Global flags]
     intx CICompilerCount                          = 3                                         {product} {ergonomic}
     uint ConcGCThreads                            = 1                                         {product} {ergonomic}
     uint G1ConcRefinementThreads                  = 4                                         {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t G1HeapRegionSize                         = 8388608                                   {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx GCDrainStackTargetSize                   = 64                                        {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 31138512896                               {product} {command line}
   size_t MarkStackSize                            = 4194304                                   {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 31138512896                               {product} {command line}
   size_t MinHeapDeltaBytes                        = 8388608                                   {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 5830732                                {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 122913754                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 122913754                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                    = 251658240                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
     bool SegmentedCodeCache                       = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedClassPointers               = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedOops                        = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseG1GC                                  = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}

Logging:
Log output configuration:
 #0: stdout all=warning uptime,level,tags
 #1: stderr all=off uptime,level,tags

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
USERNAME=root
SHELL=/bin/bash
LANG=C.UTF-8

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0xeeaf50], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0xeeaf50], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0xeeaf50], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0xc0ee30], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0xc0ee30], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0xeeaf50], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0xc0ecd0], sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
uname:Linux 5.4.0-1036-azure #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 6 18:26:30 UTC 2021 x86_64
OS uptime: 0 days 0:33 hours
libc:glibc 2.27 NPTL 2.27
rlimit (soft/hard): STACK 8192k/infinity , CORE 0k/infinity , NPROC 128328/128328 , NOFILE 1048576/1048576 , AS infinity/infinity , CPU infinity/infinity , DATA infinity/infinity , FSIZE infinity/infinity , MEMLOCK 65536k/65536k
load average:0.07 0.04 0.01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had overcommit disabled
And the amount of currently allocated memory on the system has almost reached the limit. You can see it in /proc/meminfo section of the crash log:

```
CommitLimit:    15951192 kB
Committed_AS:   15837036 kB
```

The solution is to enable heuristic overcommit handling:

```
sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=0
```

or to increase overcommit ratio:

```
sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_ratio=100
```

Answer (score 1):

`Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 31138512896 bytes` - which is about 31,14G, well above your limit of 29G.

Comment: Why is that happening when I'm passing only 29G in the java flags, `java -Xms29G -Xmx29G -jar paper-1.16.4-416.jar nogui`. Is there any way to reduce the Native memory allocation bytes

Comment: -Xmx only specifies maximum heap memory. However, Java uses various other memory types for your application, which use memory beyond what's configured for heap. For details, have a look at the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi, it's quite comprehensive.

Comment: Besides that, there are also configuration options for the different other memory types, but the best solution most likely would be to decrease your heap memory. 29 GB is already rather high.

Comment: @mytechfood Am I right that there's 63 GB of RAM on the system?

Comment: @AndrewVershinin No its Standard E4as_v4 (4 vcpus, 32 GiB memory) from AZURE

Comment: @mytechfood Then it tries to allocate almost all memory on the system, you have to reduce it's appetite somehow. Is the world file that big?

Comment: @AndrewVershinin The error is solved by `sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=0` & `sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_ratio=100
`