# Java memory leak in non-heap space

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, metaspace

I have a Java application (running under OpenJDK 1.8.0_181) that has memory issues. Specifically after some time all physical memory appears consumed and the app fails to allocate more memory. The difficult part is that it's not the heap memory that causes problems. I'm struggling to understand how to investigate it further as it's not the heap memory.

Here are types of memory crashes I got:

```
Exception in thread "eXistThread-22" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

OR

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000773200000, 142606336, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 142606336 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

In all such cases the physical memory of the server is completely consumed. Then the app is unable to allocate memory or extend the heap so it crashes.

To start with here are the results of the `top` command:

```
KiB Mem :  7867456 total,   454608 free,  6696500 used,   716348 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.   933392 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   18 root      20   0 8827048 6.180g  28028 S   0.0 82.4  24:41.10 java
```

The Java app is running with the following memory settings: `java -Xms512m -Xmx3072m`

So the app can use max 3GB of the heap space. However you can see that the java process (RES memory) already uses over 6GB RAM.

At this point it's clear I need to look at non-heap space. There is so-called Metaspace which I thought faces memory leaks. I've done the following checks:

```
# jcmd 18 GC.heap_info
18:
 PSYoungGen      total 984576K, used 647154K [0x0000000780000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 925696K, 63% used [0x0000000780000000,0x00000007a3e83970,0x00000007b8800000)
  from space 58880K, 99% used [0x00000007b8800000,0x00000007bc179030,0x00000007bc180000)
  to   space 64000K, 0% used [0x00000007bc180000,0x00000007bc180000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 1671168K, used 1048981K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000766000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 1671168K, 62% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000740065488,0x0000000766000000)
 Metaspace       used 2235431K, capacity 2246406K, committed 2252780K, reserved 2981888K
  class space    used 317765K, capacity 320038K, committed 321024K, reserved 1048576K
```

Here I see that the used memory is 647154K + 1048981K of heap and 2235431K of metaspace (non-heap). The total is 3931566K = 3840M = 3.75 GB. But what is the rest of memory consumed by the Java process then? It's a lot: 6.18 - 3.75 = 2.43 GB of RAM.

I've also checked more stats with jstat:

```
# jstat -gccapacity 18
 NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC       MCMN     MCMX      MC     CCSMN    CCSMX     CCSC    YGC    FGC
174592.0 1048576.0 1048576.0 64000.0 58880.0 925696.0   349696.0  2097152.0  1671168.0  1671168.0      0.0 2981888.0 2252780.0      0.0 1048576.0 321024.0    289    13
```

Here I calculate the entire Java memory using this formula:

```
NGCMN + S0C + S1C + EC + OGCMN + MC + CCSC = 174592 + 64000 + 58880 + 925696 + 349696 + 2252780 + 321024 = 4146668K = 3.95 GB
```

It's slightly more than 3.75 GB calculated from `GC.heap_info` but still much less that 6.18 GB consumed by the Java process.

So I'm a bit lost and I need an advice:

- How can I identify which type of Java memory is taking 2.43 GB?
- How can I limit that memory or make sure it's cleared timely to avoid OutOfMemory crashes?
- Should I set extra parameters like -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio? If so, what will be the reasonable values for those?

Comment: NativeMemoryTracking, pmap, jemalloc, async-profiler, [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi) and [the presentation](https://vimeo.com/364039638)

Comment: @apangin thanks for references! From NativeMemoryTracking I've located that the native memory leaks are in "Class" part, mmap function. However async-profiler does not catch mmap calls for some reason - the flame graph svg is empty. Could you give an advice how to catch the Class mmap leak?

Comment: This apparently means a class loader leak. The presentation I've linked above also tells about this kind of leaks. Try `jcmd VM.classloader_stats`, `jcmd GC.class_stats`, or simply create a heap dump and open it in MAT (there should be traces of class loading problem in the heap, too).

Comment: @apangin thank you! I think I've found the suspects - some threads that are never closed and class loaders that are not garbage collected.

Comment: @apangin I am facing a similar problem. I am unable to access the presentation that you have shared. Could you please share it again?

Comment: @ArjunPanicker The linked topic has the [updated reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c755fFv1Rnk) to the presentation.