# How to get maximum memory used by java program

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jvm, runtime

Is there a way to get the peak memory used at any given point during a java program run? So far I've only seen solutions that give total memory consumed.

Comment: What is the difference? How you tried to get that? Do you need information about java heap or about whole java process?

Comment: can you explain the difference between the heap/process? @talex

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi) for the memory used by a java process

Comment: It will be long explanation. Couple of chapters in book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this JDK tools for **heap** analyzis:

- `VisualVM`
- `jstat` (console [tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html))

**RSS mem** usage can be found on unix by comman line tools `ps` or `top`, or by JDK tool:

- `jcmd <pid> VM.native_memory detail.diff` (java process should be run with `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary` [JAVA_OPTS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html))

**RSS Peak** usage can be found on linux in `/proc/<pid>/status` file in `VmHWM` field ([man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)).

Comment: 1+ `jcmd` is the one I wanted to add, but your edit made that obsolete

Comment: native memory tracking doesn't include some memory areas e.g mapped byte buffers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438

Comment: Mentioned `/proc/<pid>/status` field `RssFile` (`VmHWM` includes it) and `/proc/<pid>/smaps` shows mmap mem usage.

Comment: i've never run java in any other way other than through intelliJ. how would i run my code to get RSS mem/RSS Peak on a Windows machine?