# JVM out of memory issue with Error :- Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map X bytes for committing reserved memory

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, out-of-memory, native, heap-memory

*Im facing Java OOM issue when system is loaded with traffic . I have allocated -Xmx=10G and i have been monitoring the memory via Jconsole , it's not even going till 10 Gb it throws error after 5Gb.*

It fails with below error
Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 518520832 bytes for committing reserved memory

```
    OS:DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
    
        uname:Linux 5.0.0-29-generic #31~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 18:29:21 UTC 2019 x86_64
        libc:glibc 2.27 NPTL 2.27 
        rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 44326, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
        load average:5,55 4,44 3,46
        
        /proc/meminfo:
        MemTotal:       11397468 kB
        MemFree:          133900 kB
        MemAvailable:      24040 kB
        Buffers:             600 kB
        Cached:           188880 kB
        SwapCached:        20644 kB
        Active:          9980144 kB
        Inactive:        1012376 kB
        Active(anon):    9965700 kB
        Inactive(anon):   996552 kB
        Active(file):      14444 kB
        Inactive(file):    15824 kB
        Unevictable:          16 kB
        Mlocked:              16 kB
        SwapTotal:       1003516 kB
        SwapFree:          92868 kB
        Dirty:               180 kB
        Writeback:           596 kB
        AnonPages:      10782764 kB
        Mapped:           171488 kB
        Shmem:            158936 kB
        KReclaimable:      45080 kB
        Slab:              88608 kB
        SReclaimable:      45080 kB
        SUnreclaim:        43528 kB
        KernelStack:       16800 kB
        PageTables:        76584 kB
        NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
        Bounce:                0 kB
        WritebackTmp:          0 kB
        CommitLimit:     6702248 kB
        Committed_AS:   23938048 kB
        VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
        VmallocUsed:           0 kB
        VmallocChunk:          0 kB
        Percpu:             1264 kB
        HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
        AnonHugePages:         0 kB
        ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
        ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
        CmaTotal:              0 kB
        CmaFree:               0 kB
        HugePages_Total:       0
        HugePages_Free:        0
        HugePages_Rsvd:        0
        HugePages_Surp:        0
        Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
        Hugetlb:               0 kB
        DirectMap4k:      167872 kB
        DirectMap2M:    11505664 kB
```

This is the error There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 518520832 bytes for committing reserved memory

Comment: `MemFree:          133900 kB` - your system has not enough memory to run the JVM with the given configuration. Try to reduce heap size and/or [other JVM structures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624438/3448419).

Comment: One way to help diagnose the problem is to force the JVM to allocate the memory up front by setting -Xms to match the size of -Xmx and also specify -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch