# Error occurred during initialization of VM - Could not allocate metaspace

Tags: java, linux, jvm

The metaspace requires is ~1GB

```
jenkins@android-build:~$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK_8u131/bin/java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not allocate metaspace: 1073741824 bytes
```

Here are the memory limits for user jenkins

```
jenkins@android-build:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 381421
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 8000000
open files                      (-n) 65535
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 381421
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 4000000
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Trying to replicate an OutOfMemoryError situation, hence limiting the memory with ulimit

How much more memory do I need in order to run Java programs?

My program is configured to use max 4GB of heap

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries true
    }
```

and 5GB Xmx
gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120M
```

Comment: Just to be sure. It's not running inside of a docker container? (java older than 11 can't properly detect memory limits if run within a container)

Answer (score 5):

Your Jenkins environment has a strict limitation on the amount of virtual memory (-v) a process can use. Meanwhile, JVM tends to reserve a *huge* amount of virtual memory. Note: this is not the actual memory consumption, but just a reservation of the address space, which is practically unlimited on 64-bit systems, so JVM does not  even attempt to be modest in such reservation by default.

Java process reserves virtual memory for Java Heap and for many other structures: Code Cache, Metaspace, Compressed Class Space, thread stacks etc. See [the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438) for details.

You haven't set any JVM options, so the JVM by default reserves

- 1/4 RAM for the Heap;
- 1 GB for the Compressed Class Space;
- 240 MB for the Code Cache;
- 1 MB per each thread stack, and so on.

The above answer also mentions JVM options for limiting those structures.

Here is also an [interesting post](https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/12-native-memory-tracking/) describing the experiment of reducing JVM memory usage.

Using [`jemalloc`](http://jemalloc.net/) in place of the standard libc allocator, or limiting the number of allocator arenas using [`MALLOC_ARENA_MAX`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html), allows to reduce virtual memory consumption even further.

For example, with the following command line options, JVM reserves less than 500 MB of virtual memory:

```
MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2 java -Xmx100m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m -XX:-UseCompressedClassPointers -Xss256k <args>
```

However, if possible, I'd suggest to set `ulimit -v unlimited` instead. As said above, virtual memory (unlike physical memory) is almost endless, so there is no much sense in limiting it.

Comment: curious why disabling `UseCompressedClassPointers` helps reduce virtual memory usage?

Comment: is it because it fully frees up the "Compressed Class Space" ?

Comment: @FreePeter Yes, Compressed Class Space makes sense only with `UseCompressedClassPointers`