# How to track JVM native memory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, memory-leaks, jvm

JVM native memory leak is suspected, so I want to track memory.

I tried Native tracking using the JVM tuning flag as follows, but I couldn't find a memory leak point.

```
java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail
```

Probably because of the following reasons in the document.

```
NMT in this release does not track third party native code memory allocations and JDK class libraries. 
Also, this release does not include NMT MBean in HotSpot for JMC.
```

**Is there any other way to track JVM native memory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools that you can use.
I'll refer to this excellent answer by apangin: [Java using much more memory than heap size (or size correctly Docker memory limit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438)
I strongly encourage you to read all of that but for your question, this in particular is relevant:

> There are tools and techniques for investigating issues with Java memory consumption: Native Memory Tracking, pmap, jemalloc, async-profiler.