# Large difference between k8s container memory and jvm memory used

Tags: kubernetes, memory-management, jvm

We are running a springboot application in a container (uses kafka streams). The container memory is very high (around double ~ 3.5 GB) compared to the JVM memory used (~1.5 GB).

Please help me understand what is taking up the remaining memory?

Comment: There are quite a few similar questions on SO. Have you considered searching for an answer before asking?

Comment: An excellent and deep answer already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438