# Understanding JVM Memory on Containers Environment

Tags: memory, operating-system, jvm, prometheus

I'm running a regular JVM application on containers in GCP.

The `container_memory_working_set_bytes` metric returns `4GB`, while `sum(jvm_memory_bytes_used)` returns `2GB`.

I'm trying to understand which processes are using the remaining `2GB`.

In theory, what can consume this memory? how can I understand it via Prometheus / Linux shell by `kubectl exec`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp) `jvm_memory_bytes_used` is only *heap* memory.
JVM can consume much more than that and this has already been asked and answered several times.

One of the best answers that I know about is here: [Java using much more memory than heap size (or size correctly Docker memory limit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the difference, It's was the JVM committed memory which can be found via `jvm_memory_bytes_commited`