# How to find out what RAM is used for in Heroku spring boot application that is running in "heroku-22" container?

Tags: spring, docker, heroku, jvm, ram

There is an application that deploys to Heroku using Heroku-22 Stack (default java application deploy method). There are three graphs in the Metrics section. One graph is called [Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuFyb.png) and it displays a value of 659 MB  The second graph is called [JVM: Heap Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwjTG.png), it shows a value of 145 MB, and the third graph is called [JVM: Non-Heap Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WfnN.png) and it shows a value of 188 MB. If you add 188 and 145 you get 333, although the Memory Usage graph shows 659. Is it possible to figure out what the remaining 326 MB are being used for?

I have tried different approaches:

1. Analyze Heap dump
2. Use "ps aux --sort=-rss | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB\t\t" $11}' | head" ([Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPuJK.png))

It’s not clear how to analyze RAM consumption

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624438/3448419