# Excessive Max Memory in Non-Heap for Java 17 App on Kubernetes Pod

Tags: java, kubernetes, memory-management, jvm

I have a Kubernetes Pod running a Java 17 application in a container. The Pod is configured with 2GB requested and limited memory.

For the Java 17 app, I've set the flag -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50, and the -XX:+UseContainerSupport flag is enabled by default.

I've collected JVM memory metrics (used, max, and committed) using Prometheus, and I've noticed that the non-heap memory seems to have an unusually high max value.

Here's a screenshot from a JVM Memory Grafana chart of the selected Pod:

[JVM Memory Grafana Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTFdH.png)

[MaxRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pG9Z.png)

[MaxHeapSize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7biEk.png)

I understand that besides the Java Heap, the Non-Heap (e.g., Metaspace) also plays a role and appears to be the culprit. However, I'm puzzled as to why the Non-Heap max memory is so high.

My specific questions are:

- How does Prometheus calculate jvm_memory_max_bytes?
- How can I determine why and where this additional max JVM memory for Non-Heap is coming from?

Thank you for any insights or guidance!

I have tried to use the different values for the -XX:MaxRAMPercentage flag.

I have not been able to use tools like jmap or jcmd because the image is a JRE.

Is the JProfiler suitable to help me with this problem?

Comment: Isn't MaxRam just the maximum ram of the POD?  It's set to your 2gb limit.  I suspect max means max memory of the machine, and not the JVM's max memory.  With a -XX:MaxRAMPercentage =50 would mean the JVM heap gets 1GB which is reflected in Grafana with the Max JVM heap size, and your program is taking up ~200mb of that heap.  I don't think there is any wild non-heap usage.

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438